# How to write a test for a deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, default-constructor

I have a class `A` where I deleted the default constructor.

```
class A {
  public:
    A() = delete;
    A(int a): m_myInt(a) {}
  private:
    const int m_myInt;
};

int main () {
    A foo(1);  // works perfect
    A bar;   // won't compile
}
```

How do I write a good unit test ensuring that `A bar;` remains not valid? I could write a not compiling test and take the compile error as a test requirement. I wonder, if there is a better way to write a unit test?

Comment: I'm not seeing why this requires a unit test, to be honest. How does it translate to a functional requirement?

Comment: The "unit test" in this case would need be a build script or build target that attempts to compile code that instantiates `A bar`.   The criterion for passing the unit test would be failed compilation.   The build process would need to capture that fact, and register a failed compilation as a passed test.   Depending on how much information needs to be captured, you may also wish to capture parse the error messages from the compiler in order to detect that the particular line of code caused compilation to fail.

Comment: @Peter That would be a great answer.

Comment: @Ron - yeah, okay.   I'll expand a bit, and post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2) If `std::is_trivially_constructible<T>::value` is true, provides the member constant value equal to `true`, otherwise value is `false`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible

Comment: Probably the right direction, but a needlessly restrictive choice of trait.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with a unit test that hinges on confirming that some code constructs fail to compile.   The purpose of unit testing is determining if one or more sections of code are collectively "fit for use" - and the criteria can represent functional or non-functional (e.g. quality) attributes.   If a "fit for use" criterion is "code will not compile if ....." then an obvious approach is to write a unit test that deliberately seeks to cause a failed compilation.

This is certainly a valid unit testing approach for a compiler - in which testing how the compiler responds to samples of bad code is completely appropriate as a unit test, or set of unit tests.

Given that the requirement is that default-instantiation of an `A` (to use the OP's words) "remains not valid",  the basic criterion for a passed unit test would be a failed compilation of code which performs

```
  A bar;
```

Depending on requirement, such code may need to be tested in different contexts (e.g. within an instrumented function that is a member or friend of `A`, in a unrelated function, at file scope, etc).  So this requirement may require a set of unit tests.

To implement such a test, it would be necessary for the build process to capture whether compilation fails.   A successful compilation would need to be captured as a failed test and, conversely, a failed compilation would need to be captured as a passed unit test.

Depending on how much evidence needs to be captured to justify a claim of a passed (or failed) unit test, the build process may need to capture and parse the compiler diagnostics - for example, to determine which lines in a source file actually cause compilation to fail.

Equally, there would probably need to be a unit test, or set of unit tests, that check some code constructs do compile.

Answer (score 1):

You might use traits for that:

```
static_assert(!std::is_constructible<A>::value, "!");
```